# Since the box Topology is finer than the product topology the identity map $(X,T_B) \to (X,T_P)$ is continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Since the box Topology is finer than the product topology the identity map $(X,T_B) \to (X,T_P)$ is continuous?

I need help with understanding the above argument.

Comment: As you said, $T_B$ is finer, meaning that $T_P\subseteq T_B$. This guarantees that any preimage of an open set in $(X,T_P)$ is an open set in $(X,T_B)$.

Answer (score 3):

A map is continuous iff the preimage of every open set is open.

If a space $X$ is equipped with two topologies $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_1$ is finer than $T_2$ (i.e. $T_2\subset T_1$ or any set which is open in $T_2$ is a fortiori open in $T_1$)  then the continuity condition is trivially true for the inclusion $(X, T_1) \rightarrow (X, T_2)$, so this is continuous.